# MySql how to query a substring from a mediumtext?

Tags: mysql, substring

i need a MySql statement that returns a substring of 20 words, starting at word 35, from a mediumtext column.
Any ideas how this query would look like?

Comment: If you have many rows, I'd not recommend to do it in SQL. Just use any program language to trim it.

Comment: With between 1 and 5 megabytes, the mediumtext column contains a lot of data/text, however there's only one row to fetch the text from. In regards of performance, would it be faster to do it using a programming language? (java in this case)

Comment: I depends on many things - if your data is growing fast, Server CPU power, RAM, number of clients...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to agree with @RomanNewaza but this should do it.

This will get the first 55 words assuming a space is a safe word delimiter -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ', 55) FROM tbl;
```

And this will get the last 20 words based on the same assumption -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ', -20) FROM tbl;
```

So putting these two together you end up with -

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ', 55), ' ', -20) FROM tbl;
```